# For which representations of a Lie algebra is the induced trace form basic?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, traces

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a simple Lie algebra. Let $\rho$ be a representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ on a finite-dimensional vector space $E$.
Consider now the bilinear form on $\mathfrak{g}$:
\begin{equation}
\langle X, Y \rangle_{\rho} = -\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{trace} (\rho(X) \rho(Y)).
\end{equation}

> What is a sufficient condition on $\rho$ to guarantee that $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{\rho}$ is the basic inner product?

Recall that the basic inner product is the smallest inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ such that $\langle h, h \rangle \in 2 \mathbb{Z}$ for every coroot $h$.

If $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{so}_{2n}$, then the basic inner product is $\langle X, Y \rangle = - \mathrm{trace}(XY)/2$.
So, in this case the defining representation of $\mathfrak{so}_{2n}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ does the trick.
Based on this, I thought that perhaps a nice condition would be that $\rho$ is a fundamental representation, but I am not sure how to prove this in general.

Comment: If $\mathfrak{g}$ is absolutely simple, every invariant bilinear symmetric form is a multiple of the Killing form $\kappa$, and hence also on what you call basic inner product (say $b$). So $b=\lambda\kappa$ for some scalar $\lambda$ (depending only on $\mathfrak{g}$) and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_\rho=t_\rho \kappa$ for some unique scalar $t_\rho$. So your question, as I understand it, is when $t_\rho=\lambda$? Is there a reason to work with $\mathbf{R}$ rather than $\mathbf{C}$, to avoid issues in the non-split cases?

Comment: Your definition of a basic inner product is only well-defined up to a sign. It looks like you want $\langle h, h\rangle =-2$ for a long coroot. Then $\langle h, h\rangle =-4$ for a short coroot in types $BCF$ and $=-6$ in type $G_2$. You can check this condition by considering the action of $h$ on a highest and lowest weight and perhaps the next highest and lowest. It seems to me to be a strong condition.

Comment: I believe your definition of the basic inner product only works for the simply-laced case. Usually the condition is placed on the length of the coroot corresponding to the longest roots, IIRC.